# Create HTML file using MYSQL Database & PHP with subfolders

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

is there any way we can create HTML file using MYSQL and PHP? And with subfolder?

Example: creating a page with descriptions or any contents with the link of [http://www.example.com/{folder](http://www.example.com/%7Bfolder) name}/{HTML Name File}.html

I tried but failed it

Comment: Could you please provide some more details with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For pure HTML you don't need a database or PHP.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use PHP to generate actual HTML files (i.e. `file_put_contents('path/to/file.html', $string_containing_html);`) or do you mean you want the URL to look like it’s going to a HTML file that doesn’t actually exist but you want PHP to intercept that request and render it (i.e. pretty/dynamic urls)?

Comment: Yes @rickdenhaan. That's what I meant to.

Comment: @CharlesColoso …which one? That was not a yes/no question, that was a “which one of these two different things are you trying to do” question ;-)